# Clear all back stacks without intent

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to clear all back stacks without using intent?

I have a situation need to clear all back stacks if user does something in current activity so when back button pressed application should close.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [FinishAffinity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#finishAffinity(android.app.Activity))

From Documentation:

> Finish this activity, and tries to finish all activities immediately
>   below it in the current task that have the same affinity.

in your Currnet Activity: overWrite `onBackPressed()`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(condition)
        finishAffinity();  //closes application
}
```

Requires SDK>16

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can just clear back-stack .

> I have a situation need to clear all back stacks if user does
>   something in current activity so when back button pressed application
>   should close.

you can set some `boolean` Flag variable to `true` when user do that something in that activity and then override `onBackPressed()`
and in `onBackPressed()` check for this flag if `true` the call `System.exit(0);`
.

Comment: finish() closes only current activity and previous activity in back-stack would be shown.

Comment: use `System.exit(0);`

Answer (score -1):

If you know the activity should be the only one at the moment you start it, you could use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`. From docs:

> If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will
>   cause any existing task that would be associated with the activity to
>   be cleared before the activity is started. That is, the activity
>   becomes the new root of an otherwise empty task, and any old
>   activities are finished. This can only be used in conjunction with
>   FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.

In this case, you should start the activity like that:

```
Intent i = new Intent(OldActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```